How could Bangladesh protect itself from Indian dams and barrages?
India has built dams, barrages, and hydroelectric projects on each of the rivers that flow from India into Bangladesh.
For example, the following infographic from InDepthBD shows the damage caused by them to the Ganges-Padma River System:

There are more systems like this:

Meghna River System
Chittagong River System
Brahmaputra River System

They kill two birds with one stone:

They retain water during the summer, and as a result, Bangladeshi rivers become dry
They release water during the monsoon, and as a result, Bangladesh becomes flooded

For instance, as of August 26, 2024, they have opened the flood gates of Dumbur dam in Tripura and Farakka Barrage in West Bengal. Bangladesh has been suffering the worst flood in its history in 2024. This flood has become even more devastating than the 1988 flood in terms of losses of wealth and human lives.
Although the Indian government dismissed it repeatedly (they even issued a statement from the MEA), the Bangladeshi general population has a feeling that India has done this intentionally.
How could Bangladesh protect itself from Indian dams and barrages in the long run?


Note: Please don't delete the newspaper screenshots because Bangladesh newspapers regularly remove news articles because of government orders and their own political affiliations.

Some footage [of the latest flood] on CNN now https://edition.cnn.com/2024/08/26/asia/bangladesh-flood-disaster-india-intl-hnk-dst/index.html

FYI: "barrage: a dam placed in a watercourse to increase the depth of water or to divert it into a channel for navigation or irrigation." https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/barrage

Of course, flooding never happened on those rivers before dams were erected, right? Clearly better communication (and river management) is needed, but those dams are also doing good things for those downstream.

Fact check: https://www.dw.com/en/fact-check-no-india-did-not-cause-artificial-flooding-in-bangladesh/a-70059159

@JonCuster, but those dams are also doing good things for those downstream --- and how is that?

@user366312 Sudan is getting power from Ethiopia's upstream dam; and generally, regulating a river that used to regularly flood catastrophically can be beneficial. (That even mutually agreed-upon regulation also has downsides notwithstanding.)

@Peter-ReinstateMonica, Adani takes Tk 1 lakh 26 thousand crore in capacity charge --- how about this?


How can Bangladesh protect itself from Indian dams and barrages in the
long run?


Enter into a treaty with India, that is binding and effective on both parties, governing the matter, and/or

Build their own backup dams the hold back water when India does not, and to store water received from India for the dry season.

Use its military to blow up India's dams and barrages (at the risk, of course, of starting an international war with India that is larger and more militarily powerful than Bangladesh).


To get a treaty, Bangladesh would have to give India something that India wants in exchange (but see option 3, which Bangladesh could refrain from if an adequate treaty is entered into between the countries and is honored by India).
Building backup dams costs a lot of money that wouldn't be necessary if there was an effective and enforceable treaty in place.

Bangladesh already has treaties, and India doesn't give a damn (no pun intended).

@user366312 Treaties can be improved. It would take information in considerable detail about what the treaties say and why they have not been effective, to know how they can be improved.

What about appealing to international arbitration (assuming this Q has valid grounds for concern)?  Aren't there international "laws" covering the expectations around rivers and dams?  There have been disputes about this before, not least some rivers around Israel and also the Egypt/Ethiopia dam brouhaha.

"Enter a treaty": Not much luck when there's power imbalance. See US and Mexico. I mean they have a treaty, but unless the British press is totally misleading, the reality is more like this https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2019/oct/21/the-lost-river-mexicans-fight-for-mighty-waterway-taken-by-the-us

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever The fact that a country's options aren't awesome doesn't change the fact that those are the available options. Calling in the Queen from Frozen to freeze the river isn't an option.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica International law is much more like guidelines than actual rules. India and China are the regional powers in the area, and China has plans to do this to Bangladesh as well. That leaves international interests in Bangladesh to fight for it, in opposition to both India and China.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: the negotiations there [Egypt-Ethiopia] are along the lines of "we'll blow up your dam". That kinda summarizes international law in this area.

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever I left that one off my list, but that is also an option.

@user366312 "Bangladesh already has treaties..." Maybe they could be mentioned in the question if they are relevant alongside descriptions of how India may ignore them.

Does Bangladesh have enough topography for (2) to be even an option?

@gerrit It doesn't look there's much elevation on the Indian side either, it's all very flat (at least for the Farakka barrage, I haven't looked at all of them)

@gerrit They probably wouldn't be very good for hydroelectric power generation, but they should be fine for flood and water supply management.

They could offer to make Bangladesh a US military stronghold, such as a coveted base in the Bay of Bengal in exchange for promises of the US pressuring India. What's the worst that could happen?

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever "That kinda summarizes international law"  If you say so.  On the other hand, the other answer seems to provide an alternative approach that can be explored first.  And seems less silly than item 3 on this list.  Not every pair of country operates on a dog eat dog basis and India has - Chinese - reasons not to antagonize Bangladesh overmuch.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution: if he did that, it would make the more Islamist governments that negotiated those look bad. At a quick look, those treaties were not negotiated by the AL. Alas, the military dictators that ran Bangladesh for a long time only insisted on the water sharing angle, but not  on any other aspects, like this one (flood safety).

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany: the US denies they covet such a base. OTOH the Indian press...

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever Indians, yes, but also claimed by the deposed President Sheikh Hasina, multiple times, including before the elections, but what does she know?

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany: she knows well how to lie, according the question asker. OTOH it's actually true that the military dictators that ran Bangladesh in the past were more pro-US. But if they didn't agree to a US base...

Conflicts between nations that seem unable to solve them on their own can sometimes successfully be addressed by international mediation. The idea is that a neutral arbiter would lend more credibility to the more valid ones of the various mutual grievances and claims because they are not themselves invested in the outcome.
The validity of grievances and claims could be established by comparing them with the relevant international law2, especially the Convention on the Law of the Non navigational Uses of International Watercourses. The convention essentially codifies long-standing and self-evident principles1 of "non navigable uses of international water courses", all of which seem relevant here:

Equitable and reasonable use (Art. 5.1).
Adequate watercourse protection (Art. 5.1).
Duty to cooperate (Art. 5.2).
Obligation to do no harm (Art. 7.1).
Duty to exchange information (Art. 9.1).

A third party may also be in a better position to recognize the outlines of feasible compromises.
One prerequisite would be a principal willingness to cooperate and compromise on both sides. This usually implies that the two parties are not generally hostile towards each other (which appears to be the case here) or that there are significant external incentives to come to a solution.
That mediator could be a third nation or an international body like the U.N. or one of the South-Asian regional associations, like the SAARC.

1 See e.g. Ute Mager: International Water Law, Heidelberg 2015, pp. 12-14
2 To avoid misunderstandings: Since neither nation is party to the convention, neither one is legally bound by it. But customary laws and conventions, even if not binding, let alone enforceable, can serve as yardsticks and guidelines for conflict resolution. A mediator can show that their proposals are not arbitrary but rooted in millennia of previous conflict resolution principles as well as law codified elsewhere.

"From the time of its drafting, the Convention took more than 17 years to enter into force on 17 August 2014. With the treaty having been ratified by just 36 states, the majority of countries, especially the key ones, remain outside its scope." Neither India nor Bangladesh ratified (or even signed) it, BTW.

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever I didn't say that this convention binds either party; but it is certainly relevant international law. In any case it is effectively the codification of longstanding customary principles by which to solve such conflicts. (Enforcement, even where it applies as law, is altogether another matter, as always.)

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever Confirmed by this link: https://treaties.un.org/Pages/ViewDetails.aspx?src=IND&mtdsg_no=XXVII-12&chapter=27&clang=_en

@Peter-ReinstateMonica generally when few countries sign on to a treaty, the 'customary' claim is suspect in toto. Of course countries may be objecting [just] to specific provisions, but treaties generally allow countries to enter reservations of the latter kind. (Nonetheless I upvoted your answer, as more right than wrong.)

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever Quantity does not necessarily equate quality ;-). The treaty has been signed by all the large EU members, which in my book lends it a very great deal of authority. That the United States have not signed it only adds to it ;-).

"signed by all the large EU members" -- fair enough. Sadly wikipedia didn't have map on that one. But the wiki article does mention the controversy around article 7 -- obligation not to cause harm and compensate. The broad language of the convention's article could potentially make India liable in the situation described by the OP: suddenly opening levies causing a flood. OTOH there were heavy rains in the region, and India opened like 13 dams. The excessive controversy around that one case where they didn't provide notification would be debated in that context in an arbitration case, IMHO.

BTW, earlier drafts of that article emphasized only fairness in utilization. Bangladesh actually has some such treaties with India. And one of those even says that in case of flood basically, India is not obligated to retain the water. Or rather Bangladesh is given all the excess balance. So, under that early/draft version of the  controversial article, India would probably be quite in the clear here.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica The US has only two relevant neighbors which it gets along with very well, relatively speaking, so treaties have been long signed with both. Further, the Northern border has a huge, economically significant, navigable body, with a complex lock system, and that requires special consideration. The US and its neighbors don't need the UN, and figured it out 100 years before.

@user71659 I am aware that the U.S. don't need the UN. After all, laws protect the weak.

@user71659 Also, if you try to beat Europe in terms of being historically first you are probably fighting a lost battle ;-). The Danube and the Rhine were long theaters of conflict, but when the modern European nations started to coalesce in the 19th century, treaties included river use, e.g. at the Congress of Vienna 1815. After WW2, Germany and France established a standing committee responsible for the Rhine, etc. A concrete need probably doesn't exist here either, but nonetheless we support codification of and respect for international law, in principle.
